# Sync data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logic

I hit an API which gives a list of chairs with their location. I save this data in my local database. Whenever I received updated data like add a new chair, update location of the chairs and delete a chair from the API, I must sync server data with my local database. I also assigned these chairs with different sections in the local database.

Chair server class:

1. ChairServerId
2. Description (unique key)
3. Location

Local DB class:

1. ChairLocalDBId
2. Description (Unique)
3. location

I have a Section Table in local database. It has two columns i.e. SectionID and SectionName.

Also, there is a relational table between chairs and sections. It has two columns.

I have a SectionChair Table in database has also two columns i.e. SectionID and ChairLocalDbId.

Below are different test cases:

1. Sync with same location of chairs =>

   One :If multiple chairs are coming with same location, it shouldn’t add into 
   local database. It should show a message to the user – show duplicate chairs 
   with location to the user.

   Two: First time, I did a sync and a chair (chairOne) is added with location 
   ‘locOne’ in the local database. Now, I will add one or more chairs (chairTwo) 
   with same location ‘locOne’. So, when I do Sync, it will not add chairTwo in 
   localdatabase and also not delete chairOne from the local database. It just 
   shows a message to the user – show duplicate machines with location to the 
   user.
2. Delete a chair from the Server (API) =>

   If a chair is deleted from the server, it should be deleted from the local 
   database. Validation: if a chair is assigned to any sections, it shouldn’t be 
   deleted. It should give an exception –“ please first unassigned this chair 
   from the Section and sync again.
3. Add a new chair from the Server (API) =>

   If a chair is added in the server, it should be added into local database.
4. Swapping Locations =>

   One: 3. If we swap a two or more chairs in the API, location should be also 
   swap in the local database. Example: Chair 234 on locOne location and Chair 
   345 on locTwo location in both the API and local database. After that, user 
   swap the machines in the API like Chair 234 on locTwo location and Chair 345 
   on locOne location. When I do sync, the same swap should be happen in the 
   local database and update the new location for the chair in the local 
   database.

   Two:4. Major issue: if we do swap like first point, Section should also be 
   updated into SectionChair table. Example : Chair 234 is located in 562 and is 
   assigned to Section 5 place X. It is switched with chair 789 located in 223 
   which is in Sections 8 Place Y. When synced, chair 234 should change to 
   Section 8 Place Y and chair 789 should change to Section 5 Place X.

Please suggest me a good approach.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me. You need to have shown at least an attempt at the problem when you ask questions here.

Comment: sure..m posting my code as well